# Sum values extracted from a json array based on condition

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a JSON field in a table like below

```
{
"Ui": [
    {
        "element": "TG1",
        "mention": "in",
        "time": 123
    },
    {
        "element": "TG1",
        "mention": "out",
        "time": 125
    },        
    { "element": "TG2",
        "mention": "in",
        "time": 251
    },
    {
        "element": "TG2",
        "mention": "out",
        "time": 259
    }
]
 }
```

My intention is to get something like below

```
| element  |   Timespent   |
|  TG1     |     2         |
|  TG2     |     8         |
```

but have been completely unsuccessful. 
How would I get the difference (sum of all time when mention is in - sum of all time when mention is out)?
Currently I am trying to do `sum(jsonb_extract_path(data::jsonb, 'ui','hovers')->0->'when')` to get the sum but cant figure how to recursively look into the json file and filter for mention.

Comment: Where exactly is the need for recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to extract columns from the json array:

```
select value->>'element' as element, value->>'time' as time_spent
from my_table
cross join json_array_elements(json_column->'Ui')

 element | time_spent 
-----+------------
 TG1     | 123
 TG1     | 125
 TG2     | 251
 TG2     | 259
(4 rows)
```

Modify the above query to get sums in groups by element:

```
select element, sum(time) as time_spent
from my_table
cross join lateral (
  select
    value->>'element' as element,
    case value->>'mention' when 'in' then -(value->>'time')::numeric else (value->>'time')::numeric end as time
  from json_array_elements(json_column->'Ui')) as elements
group by 1
order by 1

 element | time_spent 
---------+------------
 TG1     |          2
 TG2     |          8
(2 rows)
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3f014d9138d6a3ad7fb6246cf82ffde8)